# .htaccess HTTP to HTTPS AND non-www to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have some rules which work for directing http://domain.com to https://www.domain.com, but it doesn't work (I guess it's not matching?) for http://www.domain.com, which should redirect to https://www.domain.com. Could someone modify the below to do this? I've tried quite a few things but haven't been successful, this is my first time with .htaccess rewrite rules.

TL;DR, I need to redirect to both WWW and HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .? - [E=PROTO:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .? - [E=PROTO:https]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: I've found the following code, which somewhat works - It redirects both to https://www.domain.com, but it gives a "Too many redirects" error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www\.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: have you access to the server config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It would be better to modify this in the VirtualHost for the server.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.domain.com
 ServerAlias domain.com
 Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
 ServerName www.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /www/
 SSLEngine On
 # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That partially works, like the second one in my example. I.E, it changes to https:// www, but i get Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

This 'fix' is for many clients in cPanel environment, so it's not really possible to modify the virtualhost.

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule I'm using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

You could include `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` as the first condition to force remove https if that's neccesary...

Hope that helps...